# Deletion of question with 2 upvoted answers: How to explain tactfully that someone has misrepresented you?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Why was [How to explain tactfully that someone has misrepresented you?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/4129/2423) deleted? The 2 upvoted answers (that I again was too late to accept) can help others.

Comment: The question was deleted after two months; if you wanted to accept an answer, you had plenty of time to do it.

Comment: @HDE226868 While that's true, I don't think accepting one was the intent of this meta. I think OP wishes to know why it was deleted in the first place.

Comment: @NVZ I know that, but the OP has had a couple cases where their questions were deleted a while after they were first written, and then claimed that the questions shouldn't have been deleted in part because they were about to accept an answer. I'm saying that that argument doesn't hold water.

Comment: @HDE226868 I see.

Comment: @HDE226868 I don't obsessively monitor which questions I've accepted and not, and I never accept anything immediately as I prefer to await further answers.  I'm not sure why your comments appear to apply such a high standard to me?

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal This is not the first time you've been here; https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2199/102 was another case where you didn't improve your questions or accept an answer, and it seemed like you didn't care. You should not be surprised if low-quality questions which you seem to have abandoned are deleted.

Comment: @HDE226868 I haven't abandoned anything. I remember someone suggesting (on another SE?) a feature that would alert users of any potential closures or deletions: this appears the difficulty.

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal you have 15 questions on IPS, for wich 7 have an accepted answer... One dating from September 28 with 4 answers... If you can't walk through your own profile once in the month we won't do it for you.

Comment: It's now undeleted.

Comment: @NVZ Thanks for the update.

Comment: Please don't "update" your question in this manner.

Comment: @Catija How can I remind myself in the title by distinguishing solved vs. unsolved problems?

Comment: Answer the question and accept it? That will change the votes icon to show that it's completed.

Comment: @Catija Accepting doesn't indicate in the title if the post in question were ultimately undeleted?

Comment: Why are you trying to use Meta as your issue tracker?

Comment: I see no improvements to it from you. Undeleting it for you wasn't my brightest idea.

Comment: @NVZ I did edit it after the first deletion, after which I don't remember seeing comments for improvement. What can be further improved?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't vote to delete that one, but it looks like it was closed as unclear back in September and wasn't improved much in the two months before it was deleted.

For it to be undeleted it really needs to be edited to a point where it could be reopened. At the moment it still reads like a "what should I say, or how should I word this" and those kinds of questions generally don't fit very well here.