# Do these questions ask about how to phrase?

Tags: discussion

[This comment](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/are-these-questions-asking-about-how-to-phrase#comment9550_3022) refers to [this moderator post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1853/2423) on phrasing requests. [This](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states:

> ask us to rewrite text or otherwise tell you what to say. We are not an editing service. Questions should focus on how to generally write or decide what to say so that you can tailor them to your situation.

Are the questions beneath phrasing requests? If they are, are they on- or off-topic?

[How do I deal with people trying to convince me to wear makeup?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/12663/2423)
[How do I answer the question "why are you vegan?" honestly, without making them resent me?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/11739/2423)
[How to let tech support subtly know that I am proficient without showing off?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/10239/2423)
[How do I answer a question about not enjoying a party without revealing sensitive information](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/12808/2423)
[How do you deal with someone who's pushing you without explaining yourself?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/12435/2423)
[How can I avoid coming across as condescending when telling a coworker I can't work on an issue right now?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/14824/2423) 
[How do I respond when someone is glad their loved one's suffering will end soon due to death?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/1853/2423)
[How can I request someone to give up their seat to me on public transport if I have an invisible disability?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/14459/2423)
[How can I decline someone's business card with tact?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/14821/2423)
[How to politely request we don't eat out for lunch on my first day at new job?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/14758/2423)

Comment: This is the meta post I've been linking when VTC something for being a phrasing request: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/lets-close-questions-asking-how-to-word-phrase-something

Comment: @EmC Thanks. Added.

Comment: On the on-topic page, it states as off-topic questions that "ask us to rewrite text or otherwise tell you what to say. We are not an editing service. Questions should focus on how to generally write or decide what to say so that you can tailor them to your situation." So if you want to ask here about a particular question being a phrasing request or not that's fine, but it *is* in the help center.

Comment: Asking about ten distinct questions seems Too Broad to me. Each question should be judged by its own merits, not as part of a lumped together question that just gives a list of questions.

Answer (score 6):

One thing all those questions have that your questions don't is a clear goal rather than just asking "how do I tactfully x?" for different values of x. The questions describe detailed situations and the complications they are more specific than asking how to say a phrase in a tactful manner.

It seems to me like your real question is why so many of your questions have been closed recently. If we look at the questions you have asked recently they are all of the form "how do I tactfully x?" with very little information about the situation, or why simply speaking up isn't a sufficient solution. These make the questions poor fits for the site since they're doing little more than asking "what do I do?" or "what do I say?". Given the frequency with which you ask very similar questions that share the same fundamental flaws it's becoming increasingly difficult to believe that you are making a good faith effort to learn how this site works.

Comment: How do my downvoted questions provide "very little information about the situation, or why simply speaking up isn't a sufficient solution."? I detailed the context, and said why saying no will offend.